# Case ownership changes unintentionally with new email

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, email2case

I have a flow that does the following: as soon as a new email arrives in the system (email to case enabled), the affected case is set to Open so that the service agent sees that something new is there. However, I also have a second flow that, when a new email arrives that doesn't have a case yet, distributes the automatically generated case - based on the incoming email (decision elemenet) - to an appropriate queue. So far everything is fine.

The only problem now is that also cases that already have a direct service agent as owner are distributed to the queue again. How can I implement the rule that cases that already have a real owner are ignored?

[image]

I already tried it with a specific productline (and dedicated emails) but no real luck

[image]

The compared value is the queue id.

Kind regards
Alex